# How to evaluate this integral involving complex

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

$\int e^{(i (k' - k) x)} f(x) dx$

Is there a way to simplify this integration? I tried by parts, but something odd happened:

$\int e^{(i (k' - k) x)} f(x) dx = (2 \pi) \delta(k-k') f(x)]_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b} (2 \pi) \delta(k-k') \frac{df}{dx} dx = 0$

OBS: i really don't know complex analysis, so maybe i am missing something.

Comment: 1) Your integration by parts is erroneous : the (complex) exponential hasn't Dirac's $\delta$ as a primitive function ; it has to be a multiple of the (complex) exponential ! 2) The integral is a version of the Fourier Transform of $f$.

Comment: No reaction to my comment ? I will add that most of the time, this kind of integrals (if $a=-\infty$ and $b=\infty$ in general) aren't computed using integration techniques, but by using properties of Fourier Transform.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, i think i get what you mean :) Thank you.